# Puppeteer PDF Title and Author (metadata)

Tags: pdf, metadata, title, puppeteer, author

After all my searches and code digging didn't help, I'm asking here for a hint:

How, using Puppeteer PDF generation, do I set the metadata of the file (specifically title and author)?

I've tried setting meta tags in my HTML, but it didn't output these into the file metadata.

Comment: Try show code in file

Answer (score 11):

Puppeteer does not come with built-in functionality to edit or write metadata to a PDF.

Instead, you can install the [`exiftool`](https://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) command line utility to edit the metadata of PDFs generated with Puppeteer:

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

Then you can use the Node.js [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) function to call the command line utility from your program after the PDF has been generated:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const exec = require('util').promisify(require('child_process').exec);

const execute = async command => {
  const {stdout, stderr} = await exec(command);

  console.log((stderr || stdout).trim());
};

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://example.com/');

  await page.pdf({
    path: 'example.pdf',
  });

  await execute('exiftool -title="Example PDF" -author="John Doe" /var/www/example.com/public_html/example.pdf');

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is right, as for now Puppeeter doesn't support setting pdf metadata. But I just wanted to give a solution using a node package instead of a native library : [pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib).

You need to :

- generate the pdf with puppeeter
- use the returned buffer to load a pdf'lib's `PdfDocument`
- set the metadata you want
- send (and/or save) the result document

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'
import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib'
import fs from 'fs'

// generate pdf page as usual with puppeeter
const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.setContent(`Some html`),
const puppeeterPdf = await page.pdf()
await browser.close()

// Give the buffer to pdf-lib
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(puppeeterPdf)
pdfDoc.setTitle('A title')
pdfDoc.setAuthor('An author')
const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()

// write to disk
await fs.promises.writeFile('path/to/file.pdf', pdfBytes)
// send via http
res.send(Buffer.from(pdfBytes))
```

Comment: Just important note... setting filename is not possible chrome always uses it from URL - e.g. from URL example.com/file.pdf filename will be file.pdf but when URL is without extension e.g. example.com/somehash filename will be unfortunately somehash.pdf so URL should always end with desired filename. Puppeteer and pdf-lib have no option to set filename. Btw header `Content-Disposition: inline; filename=myfile.pdf` is ignored but `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf` is working but user can not see PDF inline in browser and must save it to disk.